# How write tests for checking behaviour during graceful shutdown in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

There is an example of my graceful shutdown:

```
function stopHandler() {
  logger.info(`Stopping server on port ${settings.port} with pid ${process.pid} started`);

  server.close(() => {
    logger.info(`Server on port ${settings.port} with pid ${process.pid} stopped`);
    process.exit();
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    logger.info(`Server on port ${settings.port} with pid ${process.pid} stop forcefully`);
    process.exit();
  }, settings.stopTimeout);
};

process.on("SIGTERM", stopHandler);
process.on("SIGINT", stopHandler);
```

How I can test this code with mocha?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It obviously depends how extensively you want to test your code, but here's a boilerplate to start with.

Some explanation:

- The code uses [`sinon`](http://sinonjs.org/) to stub two functions: `server.close()` and `process.exit()`. Stubbing them means that instead of calling those functions, a "fake function" (the stub) gets called, and you can assert *if* it got called;
- I commented out the `SIGINT` test because I found out that `mocha` uses that signal to abort the test runner. However, since both `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` use the exact same handler, that should be okay;
- Signal delivery is asynchronous, which means the tests have to be asynchronous too. I added a "once" signal handler for the to-be-tested signal, that gets called when the process is sent the signal; at that point, `stopHandler` should have been called, make your assertions, and at the end call the `done` callback to tell Mocha that the test has completed;

The code:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

// Load the module to test. This assumes it exports (at least)
// `server` and `settings`, because the test needs them.
let { server, settings } = require('./your-module');

// Don't call the stopHandler when exiting the test.
after(() => {
  process.removeAllListeners('SIGTERM');
  process.removeAllListeners('SIGINT');
})

describe('Signal handling', () => {
  [ 'SIGTERM' /*, 'SIGINT' */ ].forEach(SIGNAL => {

    describe(`${ SIGNAL }`, () => {
      let sandbox, closeStub, exitStub;

      beforeEach(() => {
        sandbox   = sinon.sandbox.create({ useFakeTimers : true });
        closeStub = sandbox.stub(server, 'close');
        exitStub  = sandbox.stub(process, 'exit');
      })

      afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore();
      })

      it(`should call 'server.close()' when receiving a ${ SIGNAL }`, done => {
        process.once(SIGNAL, () => {
          sinon.assert.calledOnce(closeStub);
          done();
        });
        process.kill(process.pid, SIGNAL);
      })

      it(`should call 'process.exit()' after ${ settings.stopTimeout } seconds when receiving a ${ SIGNAL }`, done => {
        process.once(SIGNAL, () => {
          // It shouldn't have called `process.exit()` right after the signal was sent.
          sinon.assert.notCalled(exitStub);

          // Advance the clock to a bit after the timeout.
          sandbox.clock.tick(settings.stopTimeout + 10);

          // At this point, the timeout handler should have triggered, and
          // `process.exit()` should have been called.
          sinon.assert.calledOnce(exitStub);

          // Done.
          done();
        });
        process.kill(process.pid, SIGNAL);
      })

    })

  })

})
```

Comment: This is really nice testing, thanks for sharing. Awesome answer.